# How to avoid merged cells in iReport

Tags: excel, ireport, export-to-excel, cells

Does anybody know how to display field in a one cell when exporting to excel?

I get some results merged in two cells even thought they could fit in one and another are displayed in one cell. I don't know how iReport decides how to display its results. I have a problem that excel can not sort results that are in merged cells.

I tried to add parameters

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="true"/>
```

but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Sime

Comment: Can you post the piece of your template (jrxml file) which contains fields that were merged?

Comment: Check `COLLAPSE ROW SPAN` settings in iReport. Is it set to true value?

Comment: I already tried with COLLAPSE ROW SPAN. It doesn't help. Here is the piece of jrxml file:   <textElement textAlignment="Center"> <font/></textElement>
<textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{NUMBER_OF_DOLLS}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
<reportElement x="244" y="0" width="134" height="29" key="textField"/>     <box>

Comment: Your snippet is not complete. Do you use image (I see `box` tag)?

Comment: Could you post the complete snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I found that expanding the width of the entire report and shifting cells to the right of the area where the merge happens cleaned it up for me. The columns where the merge happened was reduced to 0 in width and empty when I ran the report again. If you don't mind the extra columns being there as they are all but invisible then this solution is confirmed to work.